# 3DText - Move towards Camera - Unity

Tags: android, camera, unity-game-engine

I have an ImageTarget and when the target is detected, I am showing a 3DText. I want this text to start at the ImageTarget and move towards the Camera.

Let's say I have the camera at a distance of 50 units and the target is at 0 units. When the image is detected, I want the text to start at 0 and with an interval of 5 units, move towards the camera and when it reaches the camera (45 units or 50 units), the text should stop moving.

Can someone help me with this? I am pretty new to Unity..

Thanks in advance...

Here is what I am doing now..

```
public float distance;
public int translateInterval = 5;


void Start () {

    GameObject mainCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
    distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, mainCamera.transform.position);
}


void Update () {

    while(distance > 0)
    {
        transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * translateInterval * Time.deltaTime);
        distance -= 5;
    }

}
```

When I use this code, it text just gets displayed but doesn't seem to move.

Comment: You might want to change `distance -= 5` to `distance -= translateInterval * Time.deltaTime` and change `while` to `if`.  The while loop will execute until completion so if/when your translation works, all you'll see is an instant jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate an object between two points in 3D space [Vector3.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) is your friend! To calculate where the text should move, you can look at [Vector3.MoveTowards](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)

I recommend a good read through the Vector3 class, as it contains loads of brilliant utility methods to help us out. Well, at least to help me out because I tend to fail at Vector Math :)